# npm install vue 3 return ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3

i have a problem with my project i try with npm install but this return me all this warning and an error `npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. My project is in vuew 3

```
PS C:\DEV C\keyappfront> npm install
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN Found: postcss@7.0.39
npm WARN node_modules/postcss
npm WARN dev postcss@"^7.0.39" from the root project
npm WARN 46 more (@intervolga/optimize-cssnano-plugin, …)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peerOptional postcss@">=8.0.9" from postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN node_modules/postcss-load-config
npm WARN postcss-load-config@"^3.1.0" from @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@2.2.17
npm WARN node_modules/@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat
npm WARN 1 more (tailwindcss)
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: postcss@8.4.18
npm WARN node_modules/postcss
npm WARN peerOptional postcss@">=8.0.9" from postcss-load-config@3.1.4
npm WARN node_modules/postcss-load-config
npm WARN postcss-load-config@"^3.1.0" from @tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@2.2.17
npm WARN node_modules/@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat
npm WARN 1 more (tailwindcss)
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: vue-class-component@7.2.6
npm WARN Found: vue@3.2.39
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN vue@"^3.0.0" from the root project
npm WARN 12 more (@headlessui/vue, @heroicons/vue, …)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-class-component@7.2.6
npm WARN node_modules/vue-property-decorator/node_modules/vue-class-component
npm WARN vue-class-component@"^7.1.0" from vue-property-decorator@8.5.1
npm WARN node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.7.13
npm WARN node_modules/vue
npm WARN peer vue@"^2.0.0" from vue-class-component@7.2.6
npm WARN node_modules/vue-property-decorator/node_modules/vue-class-component
npm WARN vue-class-component@"^7.1.0" from vue-property-decorator@8.5.1
npm WARN node_modules/vue-property-decorator
npm ERR! Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

I have this configuration in my package.json, i delete the node_modules folder and try to install again but the problem persist, i try to update in the package.json the version of package like `"vue-property-decorator": "^8.5.1",` but the problem continue...

```json
{
  "name": "vue3",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.0.0",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.1",
    "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs": "^1.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.4",
    "chart.js": "^3.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "vee-validate": "^4.7.1",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex-persist": "^3.1.3",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.2.17",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17",
    "typescript": "~3.9.3",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {},
    "overrides": [
      {
        "files": [
          "**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)",
          "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)"
        ],
        "env": {
          "jest": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any idea or any suggestion for fix this problem? i really need it, thank you!

Comment: Do you have a registry in your npmrc? You can check in the file or with the command `npm config get registry`; if it's not the default registry (or whichever you're intending to use) that could be the issue.

Comment: Hey Zac, i execute the command ```npm config get registry``` and return ```https://registry.npmjs.org/```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem here is that use a similar name that library in nodejs, i just change this

```
{
  "name": "vue3",
}
```

and install npm i again, with change the name of my project all work again!